Captcha image not showing Laravel mewebstudio captcha
I'm using Mewebstudio Captcha package: https://github.com/mewebstudio/captcha
This is my code:
<div class="flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
  <img src="{{ captcha_src() }}" alt="captcha" />
  <input type="text" name="captcha" id="captcha" onkeydown="clearError(this)" 
    class="bg-white border mt-2 border-primary text-gray-900 sm:text-sm rounded-lg focus:ring-primary focus:border-primary block w-full p-2.5" 
    placeholder="Captcha" required="" />
  <p id="error_captcha" class="error text-sm text-red-600 dark:text-red-500"></p>
</div>

On the web it's not showing the image of captcha:

It only shows the alt text.

Please help me, thank you!
